# What's a good way to handle url parameters types?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Imagine an app with the following `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^double/(?P<number>\d+)/$', views.double),
)
```

And this `views.py`:

```
def double(request, number=42):
    return HttpResponse(2*number)
```

Obviously, I want `number` to be always taken as an int.  When querying `/double/5/`, I'll always expect to get `10`, not `55`.

Are there any good way to handle the parameters typing within Django urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a decorator-based solution:

```
def param_type(**type_spec):
    def deco(f):
        def view(request, **kwargs):
            for k, type_ in type_spec.items():
                kwargs[k] = type_(kwargs[k])
            return f(request, **kwargs)
        return view
    return deco

@param_type(number=int)
def double(request, number=42):
    return HttpResponse(2*number)
```

Comment: Thanks !  But is it considered as a good practise ?  Or should url params typing be considered like something to avoid ?

Comment: @Anto, I personally don't use automatic type conversion decorator. I just convert it manually in the view code.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/hM3bepcAbJY) says that auto-conversion isn't a good solution:

> Note that automatic conversion wouldn't be a good plan, either. For
>   example, the next version of my blog converts URLs like 2008/2/25/ to
>   2008/02/25/ because I want a canonical form. So I need to know if
>   \d{1,2} matches one of two digits, even if the first one is 0.
>   Auto-conversion to an integer would remove that capability (and it's
>   not hard to think of other cases like this). So you'd need
>   configurabiliy.

It also suggests a solution based on a decorator, but I'm not really convinced, it sounds a bit burdensome:

> One solution to your problem could be to write a decorator that takes
>   a list of types (plus something like None for "don't care") and
>   automatically converts argument N to the type in the N-th element of
>   the list before calling your function

Answer (score 0):

Anto,

I think your question is more related to the url. `(?P<number>\d+)` is a regular expression stating `\d` only allowing digits it's the same as `[0-9]`. The `+` symbol tells it need 1 or more digits. So if you would try to insert something like `double/notanumber/` it will not work.

Knowing this you can safely assume that:

> 1: number will always have a value
>
> 2: number will always be a integer (even that django gives it back as a unicode)

I made a small change to your function:

```
def double(request, number): # removed the =42 because number can never be empty
  return HttpResponse(2 * int(number)) # Converted your number to an integer
```

Comment: I understood that, but my question is really about: what's the *best practice* to handle the type of this `number` arg knowing that 1/ it will always be returned by the url resolver as a string and 2/ I will always need an integer.  It's really a question about best practice, sorry if I wasn't clear enough ;)

Comment: I think if you know it's always a `number` and always want it as a `integer` you could just simply use `int()`